# What is the best data structure to represent a multigraph using STL in C++?

Tags: c++, data-structures, graph

I'm looking for some data structure to store a multigraph in C++ but I want to make use of the STL as much as possible. Currently I am using something similar to a seperate chaining hash table: `std::map<int,std::vector<int>>`. The key of the map is the vertex and the value is a `std::vector<int>` that contains all of the different vertices that form an edge with the key.

I'm mainly interested in O(1) lookups to see whether or not a vertex shares an edge with another vertex. Since this is an unweighted multigraph the vertex could share multiple edges with another vertex.

The graph is guaranteed to have an eulerian circuit and hamiltonian circuit, but I'm not sure if that is relevant or not.

Do you guys have any recommendations for a better data structure using the STL than `std::map<int,std::vector<int>>`?

Comment: `std::map` does not provide `O(1)` lookup, it has `O(logN)` lookup. You need `std::unordered_map` for `O(1)` lookup.

Comment: You cannot beat an adjacency matrix in terms of sheer speed.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks!

Comment: @n.m. How can you use an adjacency matrix for a multigraph? I would have used one if it were not a multigraph.

Comment: Matrix cells can contain any data. You can put the number of edges between the corresponding vertices there, or a list/set/container of edges if edges need to carry additional data.

Comment: Have you considered `std::multimap` or `std::unordered_multimap`?

Comment: You also have a problem with the adjacency list being O(n) on a dense graph. You can reduce that to log n by keeping it sorted, but you can do better with https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multiset (although test it, I had some trouble understanding the "equal_range" lookup iteration the first time I used it.) Assuming the number of edges between two vertices is small compared to the total number of vertices, this should be O(1), although with some nasty constants compared to a full adjacency matrix, which takes space, but is fast. (If dense, already using that much space.)

Comment: Do you have any guarantees or domain knowledge about number of edges M vs number of vertices N? In the worst case, M can be infinite (multigraph). Is M closer to N or N*N?

Comment: @KennyOstrom M is definitely closer to N for this multigraph.

Comment: My first recommendation would be to look for an existing graph library. Documented, publicly tested, probably already optimized. For home-projects, you say you mainly want fast lookup if edges are connected, so ... do you care that it's a multigraph? You can kind of ignore all the extras and use unordered_map<unordered_set>. I mention that option because multiple edges don't matter for "is there an edge".

Answer (score 0):

If the number of vertices N is small, it's probably easiest to use an adjacency matrix `unordered_map<int, unordered_map<int, int>> graph`, where `graph[u][v]` is the number of edges from `u` to `v`.

If your vertex numbers all range from 0 to N–1, or 1 to N, or similar, you can simplify this to `vector<vector<int>> graph`, or even `int graph[][]` if N is known at compile time.

If N is large, and if the graph is sparse, as you indicated (since M ≈ N), it's probably best to use a set for each vertex: `unordered_map<int, unordered_set<int>> graph` or `vector<unordered_set<int>> graph`, where `graph[u]` is the set of all vertices `v` with an edge from `u` to `v`.

Notice that I'm using the `unordered_map` and `unordered_set` collections, which provide O(1) access on average. In the worst case, their performance is linear in the size of the map or set, as with any hash-based container.

And if you don't want to deal with all this and want a ready-made solution, consider the Boost Graph Library, NGraph, LEMON, or Google OR-Tools.